# SOLVED: Cordova Gradle project: need to override platformBuildVersionCode

Tags: cordova, gradle, build.gradle

I've got a dilemma as to how to override the default platformBuildVersionCode and platformBuildVersionName values being added to an apk manifest by the gradle build and AAPT process.
The reason I need to do this is for a legacy app that was previously built with older Cordova (v9.0.0) and gradle versions (v4.2.2?) that generated the following in the apk's manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx.yyy.zzz"
    android:versionCode="21200"
    android:versionName="2.1.2"
    android:compileSdkVersion="28"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="9"
    platformBuildVersionCode="21200"
    platformBuildVersionName="2.1.2">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    ...
```

I'm not 100% sure why the platformBuildVersionCode and platformBuildVersionName value were set during the earlier Gradle build with the versionCode and versionName values applied (possibly this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124227171?) but the app was published with these, so now gotta live with it.
The app uses PouchDB to store data in indexedDB and needs the associated data to stay available via the update.

I'm now trying to build with Cordova (v12.0.0) and Gradle v7.6.3 with updated plugins and targetSDKs but here's what's being generated in the appk's manifest:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx.yyy.zzz"
    android:versionCode="21300"
    android:versionName="2.1.3"
    android:compileSdkVersion="33"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="13"
    platformBuildVersionCode="33"
    platformBuildVersionName="13">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="24"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    ...
```

A new install works OK, but it won't install as an update from an older installation as Android sees the platformBuildVersionCode as now being lower. (Error: The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name.)

To update the platformBuild values, I've tried specifying the platformBuildVersionCode ("21300") and platformBuildVersionName ("2.1.3") in config.xml and also in AndroidManifest.xml but the settings appear to be ignored or overridden at a later point.

I've also tried adding the respective lines below into the gradle.build file but that causes a build error: 'Could not find method platformBuildVersionCode() for arguments [21300]...'.

```
android { 
    namespace cordovaConfig.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId cordovaConfig.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE

        minSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MIN_SDK_VERSION
        if (cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION != null) {
            maxSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION
        }
        targetSdkVersion cordovaConfig.SDK_VERSION
        compileSdkVersion cordovaConfig.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
        platformBuildVersionCode 21300
        platformBuildVersionName "2.1.3"
    }
...
```

(Note: I've tried both quoted and unquoted variations for the platformBuildVersionCode with the same error result.)

I'm starting to suspect it's the AAPT process that may be adding these and overriding anything supplied via config.xml or AndroidManifest.xml in the build process.
Any suggestions welcome on how I can get the apk's Manifest to have platformBuildVersionCode="21300" (and platformBuildVersionName "2.1.3")?

Thanks in advance!

ISSUE SOLVED:

1. I've subsequently identified that changing the manifest could be done using Apktool but...
2. The update issue experienced was actually due to something else: it was occurring for debug builds because the debug key had changed (perhaps due to changing the Android build tool version?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved